# Generating the edit path for a nested resource referenced by multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes, nested

In routes.rb:

```
resources :cars do
  resources :reviews
end

resources :motorcycles do
  resources :reviews
end
```

In ReviewsController:

```
before_filter :find_parent

def show
  @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @review }
  end
end

def edit
  @review = Review.find(params[:id])
end

# ...
def find_parent
  @parent = nil
  if params[:car_id]
    @parent = Car.find(params[:car_id])
  elsif params[:motorcycle_id]
    @parent = Motorcycle.find(params[:motorcycle_id])
  end
end
```

Generating the "show" link for a Review is simply (this works):

```
= link_to "Show", [@parent, @review]
```

Similarly I would like to reference a generic edit path for a Review, something like (this does not work):

```
= link_to "Edit", [@parent, @review], :action => 'edit'
```

Does anyone know if this is possible or, if not, how this might be accomplished?

Comment: It turns out the answer I am looking for can be found with the URL helper "edit_polymorphic_path" (see: http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes).  In order to get the link I am attempting above I was able to accomplish this with: edit_polymorphic_path([@parent, @review])

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out the answer I am looking for can be found with the URL helper "edit_polymorphic_path" (see: http://rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes). In order to get the link I am attempting above I was able to accomplish this with:

```
edit_polymorphic_path([@parent, @review])
```

Comment: This has changed to `edit_polymorphic_path(@parent, @review)` in Rails 4

Comment: I don't know about Rails 4 but in Rails 5 you do need the square brackets: edit_polymorphic_path([@parent, @review])

Answer (score 17):

```
link_to 'Edit Review', [:edit, @parent, @review]
```

Comment: This is super cool, thanks!! Do you know how to get something like this without using the "link_to" helper?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need here is a polymorphic assocation. Ryan Bates at Railscasts.com explains it perfectly.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

It will make it easy for you to have things like:

User, Manager, Note

A user can have many notes
A manager can have many notes
A note can belong to a user OR a manager

users/1/notes/edit
managers/1/notes/edit

The Railscast will explain how to do it :)

EDIT:

```
def edit
  @reviewable= find_reviewable
  @reviews= @reviewable.reviews
end

private

def find_reviewable
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
      return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

Then in your link to, it would be something like:

```
link_to 'Edit Review', edit_review_path([@reviewable, :reviews])
```

^^ Not tested.

Comment: In fact I do have a polymorphic association with the Review model:

class Review, belongs_to :reviewables, :polymorphic => true
class Car, has_many :reviews, :as => :reviewable
class Motorcycle, has_many :reviews, :as => :reviewable

So there is nothing different from what I am doing than what is mentioned in the Railscast unfortunately and it does not address the question of how to get the "edit" route for such an association.

Comment: Did you watch the entire Railscast? He uses:  @commentable = find_commentable

And he has the find_commentable method to determine which class he is editing...